# Sampling a random $m$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ uniformly

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, euclidean-geometry, random

Let $G_{n,m}$ be the Grassmanian manifold, the set of $m$-dimensional linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I read in the book of Verschynin that one can sample a random element $E \in G_{n,m}$ with uniform distribution in $G_{n,m}$ by computing the column span of a random $n \times m$ Gaussian random matrix with i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ entries (meanzero with unit variance).

Can anyone give me an hint of how to prove rigorously that this object has uniform distribution in  $G_{n,m})$? Where does gaussianity play a role?

Comment: Thank you. For generating a random orthogonal matrix I read that one should sample a matrix with i.i.d. gaussian entries $\sim N(0,1)$ and then apply gram schmidt procedure to such a matrix. Is this equivalent to what you describe (QR decomposition)?

Comment: There is yet another way to generate arbitrary $n \times n$ orthogonal matrices by taking $N_1,...N_n$ any unit norm $n$ dimensional vectors, then making the product of the $n$ corresponding so-called Householder matrices : $(I_k-2N_kN_k^T)$ (matrices of symmetries wrt hyperplanes with normal vector $N_k$).

Answer (score 1):

The gaussianity is important because the Gaussian Orthogonal Ensemble is orthogonally invariant (which is the usual reason for Gaussian variables). The method comes from the following remark of G. W. Stewart (see the reference below):

*Stewart, G. W.*, [**The efficient generation of random orthogonal matrices with an application to condition estimators. (With mircofiche section)**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0717034), SIAM J. Numer. Anal. 17, 403-409 (1980). [ZBL0443.65027](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0443.65027).

To generate a random orthogonal matrix uniformly, generate an i.i.d. Gaussian matrix, $G,$ compute the QR decomposition $G = QR,$ then $Q$ is the random orthogonal matrix you seek. Extension of this to arbitrary grassmannians should be easy.

Comment: Thank you. How is generating E related to generating a random orthogonal matrix?

Comment: @QuantumLogarithm The first $k$ columns of the random orthogonal matrix generate the random subspace.

Comment: Thank you! I found in a text that the space  can be sampled by computing the image (column span) of a $n \times m$ matrix with entries being i.i.d. and having standard normal distribution (not necessarily of a random orthogonal matrix). Is this because the image of  and the image of  are the same?

Comment: @QuantumLogarithm Yes, that makes sense (since the $R$ is upper triangular, it preserves the column span.